# Push notification from push.apple.com

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

I can get push messages in my iPhone application using gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com. How can I test this with real address gateway.push.apple.com?

Someone said that you cannot test this with a real address: If you can send push messages using the test address, you don't need make any thing before you send your application to the App Store. You will not encounter any problems. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

There is two mode for any app development and production.

When app is in development mode then you need to use the "development push certificate" and "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" address.

When you are planning to push the app to store you must need to use "distribution push certificate" and to make it work properly you need to use "gateway.push.apple.com" address. You must need to change the address and also put the proper certificate in server side when you are going to publish. If there is any mismatch between certificates and address notification won't work.

**Development Push Certificate:** gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

**Adhoc/Distribution Push Certificate:** gateway.push.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

YES, we can't test with Appstore distribution certificate . But you can test production environment using Adhoc distribution certificates(gateway.push.apple.com url).